# Problems using Developer Command Prompt for vs2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently reading the sixth edition of Windows Programming. This book requires the use of C#, rather than c++ which I am familiar with so I am reading Chapter Zero .NET by Charles Petzold. In this free pdf, it tells me to use the Command line for Visual Studios, which I googled how to find and came up with the answer of using Developer Command Prompt for vs2013. it tells me to enter in the following code into a notepad file, which just displays to the console I'm assuming.

```
// --------------------------------------------
// FirstProgram.cs (c) 2006 by Charles Petzold
// --------------------------------------------

class FirstProgram
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, Microsoft .NET Framework!");
    }
}
```

Now, after I enter this into a notepad and save it as "firstprogram.cs", I am told to go into the Developer Command Prompt for VS2013 and enter "csc firstprogram.cs". Which is supposed to compile my Code into a C# from the csc.exe file in my computer. However, when I enter in this code, it comes up with the message:

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 12.0.30723.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

error CS2001: Source file 'firstprogram.cs' could not be found
warning CS2000: No source files specified

Please help me. This is very annoying. Would it be better to just use my Visual Studio 2013 even though the pdf says to use this first? And is my Visual Studio 2013 supposed to run off of an application called Blend?

Comment: Assuming you familiar with C++ and know how to use its command line compiler (`cl.exe` if you are using Microsoft's version) you should be able to directly transfer that knowledge to compiling CS sources with csc.exe... If you need help on arguments - `csc /?`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've been using CodeBlocks for my C++, not a command prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once in the command prompt, navigate to the folder where FirstProgram.cs is located and execute the command there. Maybe you're better off just using Visual Studio, although figuring this out won't hurt you.

To navigate, use `cd <folder_path>`.

Comment: I'm trying this but it is not working for me. It automatically places me in C:\Program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>. Right after > is where I have the ability to enter something. I try doing "cd C:\cs programs\firstprogram.cs" and it tells me the directory is invalid, when it is the exact place I've saved it. I've also tried using cd C: just to get to my C drive and navigate from there using dir, and it will not work.

Comment: @user3806603: Use quotes if there are spaces in the path: `cd "C:\cs programs\firstprogram.cs"`

Comment: it still tells me the directory name is invalid. Do I maybe have to save it to my Visual Studio 12.0 folder?

Comment: @user3806603: No, double check the path and make sure it's correct.

Comment: @user3806603: actually, it's cd "C:\cs programs", without the file name. I missed that.

Comment: Thank you so much, this last one worked. And could you tell me if VS2013 is through an app called "Blend"? I see everyone else saying "Go to the start Menu of Vs and go through your tools and external tools". I dont have an external in my tools and didn't know if I got some knock off version, although it was free from the Microsoft website

Comment: @user3806603: No, it should be called Visual Studio 2013 (or something like that with Express in it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change directory (CD) to the directory that contains the source file before compiling it.

From the command prompt, if you do "dir firstprogram.cs" it will say 0 files found, I'm guessing.